# Divide an array into K number of parts such that each part is less than N. Also, maximize the sum of all parts

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Divide an array into K number of parts such that each part is less than N. Also, maximize the sum of all parts. If such configuration is not possible return -1.

For ex-

```
Array - 5,3,2,7,8,9

K - 3
N - 71

Solution- 53 + 27 + 89 = 169
```

Can someone suggest an efficient algorithm for this ?

Comment: "maximize the sum of all parts" a wired phrasing , does that mean get the max of the sum of each array which contains <= N items . 
then your example should be  Max(5+3,2+7,8+9)  ..?? \

Comment: Sum of all the parts should be maximum. If Array =  K1 | K2 | K3 then, K1+K2+K3 should be maximum